# NSString - convert number (e.g. "ONE") to digit (e.g. "1")

Tags: nsstring, nsnumber

I'd like to convert a number e.g. "ONE", "TWO", "THREE" to a digit value e.g. "1", "2", "3".

I can easily do this for my limited subset of numbers by doing something like

```
if([number isEqualToString:@"ONE") return @"1";
```

but this doesn't strike me as a very efficient, robust or succinct approach.

Comment: you should go for an artificial intelligence !!!!

Answer (score 0):

I found this text: [Method for the Natural Language Recognition of Numbers](http://www.google.com/patents/about/11_629_551_Method_for_the_Natural_Langua.html?id=4t2vAAAAEBAJ). It's exactly you want and is very precise. But,  I didn't found codes. You can search more or ask to author for the algorithm.